# Compare Values and return String

Tags: java

I have **ltp** and **s1** , **s2** and **s3** values

(s1 , s2 , s3 denotes suppourt1 , suppourt2 , suppourt3 )

What I am trying to achieve is that ,

If the ltp is 2 points near S1 , display S1

If the ltp is 2 points near S2 , display S2

If the ltp is 2 points near S3 , display S3

I have tried using this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double ltp = 15.45;

        double s1 = 18.34;

        double s2 = 16.34;

        double s3 = 10.34;

        double s1Level = ltp - s1;

        double s2Level = ltp - s2;

        double s3Level = ltp - s3;
        
        

        if (s1Level <= 2) {
            System.out.println("S1");
        }

        else if (s2Level <= 2) {
            System.out.println("S2");

        }

        else if (s3Level <= 2) {
            System.out.println("S3");
        }

    }

}
```

Here **ltp** is 15.45 and its near **s2** 16.34 , I was expecting S2.

Comment: What output did you expect? Why did you expect it? What output did you get instead?

Comment: You are not thinking of cases where the difference might be a negative number. Either use some method to turn your calculated subtractions s1Level etc. into absolut values, or change your if conditions to `if (s1Level >= -2 && s1Level <= 2)`

Comment: Also, using `else if` won't help if all the deltas are within the range.  Which one do you want?  The smallest? Largest?  All of them?

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting a larger number from a smaller number, so you are getting a negative value for `s1Level` which of course will always be lower than 2.  This means you will never reach the `else if` for `s2Level` since `s1Level <= 2` is true.

If you want to compare the absolute values of the subtraction, simply use `Math.abs(yourValue)` which will always return the positive value of the number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double ltp = 15.45;

    double s1 = 18.34;
    double s2 = 16.34;
    double s3 = 10.34;

    double s1Level = Math.abs(ltp - s1);
    double s2Level = Math.abs(ltp - s2);
    double s3Level = Math.abs(ltp - s3);

    if (s1Level <= 2) {
        System.out.println("S1");
    }
    else if (s2Level <= 2) {
        System.out.println("S2");

    }
    else if (s3Level <= 2) {
        System.out.println("S3");
    }
}
```